# Multiple user/organisation jekyll projects on github

Tags: c#, javascript, ruby, github

Is it possible to create another user page somehow? I already have a user page that is my own account name, i.e. myusername.github.com, but I want to put another page jekyll project up to be hosted. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each project you start on GitHub can also have its own site, via [GitHub Pages](http://pages.github.com/). Its content lives in a branch called `gh-pages` in the repository of that project.